# Azure Graph API 403 Error using Java tutorial

Tags: java, azure, graph

I’ve been working through a doc at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java

But when I run the project, I’m redirected to the ADFS login page and after authentication im receiving this error:

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://graph.windows.net/swisherint.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=2013-04-05

I get this error when I run from local host.  I also deployed the sample app to Azure and getting the same error.

I've added permissions to Graph API with read directory permissions in active directory > App Registrations > Required permissions. I also added Windows Azure Active Directory permissions (sign in and read user profile)

Is this a common error?  Am I using the wrong version of the Graph API? I've tried several solutions from other questions but not working.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Azure Graph API requires the URI connection type, instead of the HttpUrlConnection the java tutorial used.  This works without the 403 error:

```
       try{
        // OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit:
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

        // Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...})
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://graph.windows.net/swisherint.onmicrosoft.com/users");
        // Specify values for the following required parameters
        builder.setParameter("api-version", "1.6");
        // Specify values for optional parameters, as needed
        // builder.setParameter("$filter", "startswith(displayName,'A')");
        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }

        users =  EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Thanks for responding!

KB

Comment: Works Perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the new offical document reference for AAD Graph API [`Get Users`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers), it seems the `api-version` property in the code should be changed to `1.6`. Please try it.

Meanwhile, there is an [Error code reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling#ErrorCodeReference) list that you can find the description of the common error code `403` for AAD Graph API calling. And be checking whether your issue is belong to the one of the errors `Authentication_Unauthorized`, `Authorization_RequestDenied` & `Directory_QuotaExceeded`.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.